# Run 3.5 GB .sql file on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server on Windows 8, 32bit, 2GB memory. I want to execute a `.sql` file of 3.5 GB size.

Tried doing:

1. SSMS - Query thr UI - insufficient memory exception - NO LUCK
2. sqlcmd - insufficient memory exception - NO LUCK
3. split up the file into 18 files of 200 MB. sqlcmd each of them - NO LUCK
   (btw no editor can open up such a huge file. Even 200MB file contains ~18,00,000 line. suggestions are welcome)
4. put GO after each DML statement in the `.sql`, to reduce redo log size - NO LUCK
   (amazingly it did work for my other 280MB file)

Would `.bak` file help ?

Is there (I hope there is) a way to do what I'm trying to do, in a good way ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are these a bunch of INSERT statements? You could try breaking the file into smaller groups of statements and run them sequentially. Then your question is how to split up the SQL file properly.

Comment: Also, most hex editors and plaintext editors that ignore newlines can open files of any size with linear time. However, I wouldn't recommend splitting it manually unless you only need to do it a couple times. There are tools for that if you Google.

Comment: Why are you running Windows 8 in 32 bit? Yes it's still supported but come on, it's 2012. This is like trying to run Vista on a 386. Why are you running a SQL script that is 3.5 GB? Have you considered taking a backup and restoring it?

Comment: I have trouble conceiving of a 3.5 GB SQL script unless it's literally a script of every value in a database.  And there are better ways to transfer data than that.

Comment: @Vortico: yes..i've used a tool called hjsplit to spilt the file. Manually spliting it would be a nightmare anyway. And yes, there are inserts as well as create table queries. but one table named HISTORY that is causing all the pain.. in that there are blobs, long email texts and several other big data in that table. So...

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I know, but I'm on my workstation, can't help for now at least. The reason why I'm running 3.5 GB is because my client could not provide anything other than that.. not even .bak :( Data is not with me. I was wondering if we could do something with Java..but then also there may be issue of escaping characters from the column data. Any idea... ?

Comment: I see you tried sqlcmd and that didn't work.  Out of curiosity, did you try osql -i as well?  I've used that for a 1.8 GB file before with success

Comment: I suggest you stop looking at the technical issues and invest some time in ensuring that you have appropriate access to the client's data and systems. Why can't the client provide the data as a .bak? If they have the know-how to generate a .sql file they should be able to provide a .bak file. Do you actually have the necessary access to the client's data and systems to do your job? If not, why not? Does your contract with them specify your requirements and expectations? Otherwise there is a risk that you waste a lot of time, possibly at your own expense, in solving this.

Answer (score 3):

```
According to msdn  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx

1) Open a command prompt window.
2) In the Command Prompt window, type: sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName(local) -i C:\myScript.sql(path where sql script exists)
3) Press ENTER.
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run a `17.9 GB` file using [osql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) with something similar to the following command line by running it locally from command prompt. It may take quite a long time though.

```
osql -S . -d Test -E -i script.sql
```